# How to manipulate value taken from form

Tags: javascript, html

I am taking value from the user inside the form and doing calculations inside new variable by using those values which user input inside the form but I cannot figure out why my code is not working.

```js
function click() {
  var l = document.getElementById('l');
  var b = document.getElementById('b');
  var a = document.getElementById('area');
  var area = l.value * b.value;
  a.innerHTML = "The ans is " + area;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Length of the triangle: </label>
  <br>
  <input id="l" type="text" placeholder="Length">
  <br>
  <label>Base of the triangle</label>
  <br>
  <input id="b" type="text" placeholder="Base">
  <br>
</form>
<p id=area></p>
<button type="button" onclick="click()">Click:</button>
```

I think i have done everything fine then why on chrome it doesnt show the correct ans.Please help on thsi one

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that inline handlers have a [very peculiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) scope chain. They're surrounded inside two `with`s: one for the document, and one for the element on which the inline handler exists. For example, with

```
<button id="button" onclick="<<CODE HERE>>">
```

When clicked, the effect will be similar to as if the following was executed:

```
with (document) {
  with (button) {
    <<CODE HERE>>
  }
}
```

When you reference `click` inside one of these handlers, it will first try to find a `click` property on the element, *and it finds one*: it refers to `HTMLButtonElement.prototype.click`:

```html
<form>
  <label>Length of the triangle: </label><br>
  <input id="l" type="text" placeholder="Length"><br>
  <label>Base of the triangle</label><br>
  <input id="b" type="text" placeholder="Base"><br>
</form>
<p id=area></p>
<button
  id="button"
  onclick="console.log(click === button.click, click === HTMLButtonElement.prototype.click)"
>Click:</button>
```

As a result, clicking the button results in `HTMLButton.prototype.click` being called on that button, which, here, does nothing, which is why you're not seeing any results, and not even an error message.

Either use a different variable name:

```js
function handleClick() {
  var l = document.getElementById('l');
  var b = document.getElementById('b');
  var a = document.getElementById('area');
  var area = l.value * b.value;
  a.innerHTML = "The ans is " + area;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Length of the triangle: </label><br>
  <input id="l" type="text" placeholder="Length"><br>
  <label>Base of the triangle</label><br>
  <input id="b" type="text" placeholder="Base"><br>
</form>
<p id=area></p>
<button onclick="handleClick()"
>Click:</button>
```

Or, even better, [avoid inline handlers entirely, since they behave so weirdly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) - attach the listener properly using Javascript instead. Using `addEventListener` also lets you avoid global variable pollution, which is inelegant and can lead to bugs and messy code.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var l = document.getElementById('l');
  var b = document.getElementById('b');
  var a = document.getElementById('area');
  var area = l.value * b.value;
  a.textContent = "The ans is " + area;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Length of the triangle: </label><br>
  <input id="l" type="text" placeholder="Length"><br>
  <label>Base of the triangle</label><br>
  <input id="b" type="text" placeholder="Base"><br>
</form>
<p id=area></p>
<button>Click:</button>
```

Comment: actually i was using addevent listner for a long time but wanna do it by onclick daymn it was such a small mistake i just have to change the name of the function. Thanks for the solution tho

Comment: It would be a great idea to get into the habit of strongly preferring to *avoid* inline handlers. They have way too many problems.

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)